# What is a simple way to get ACID transactions with persistence on the local file system (in Java)?

Tags: java, filesystems, persistence, synchronized

I'm working on a small (java) project where a website needs to maintain a (preferably comma-separated) list of registered e-mail addresses, nothing else, and be able to check if an address is in the list. I have no control over the hosting or the server's lack of database support.

Prevayler seemed a good solution, but the website is a ghost town, with example code missing from just about everywhere it's supposed to be, so I'm a little wary.

What other options are recommended for such a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an embedded database like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) or [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)/[JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/). They need no installation and can use simple files as their storage mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, prevayler and its historical concurrent, [space4j](http://www.space4j.org/), are really good candidates for such a simple case. They're far simpler than DB, provides however some useful concepts and are way fast (since in fact FS is only a backup of the in-memory datastore.

Comment: Are they really a good solution if fully ACID is needed? Do they fully support all 4 elements? Granted, fully ACID is not needed in all situations.

Comment: Space4j also offers transparent cluster and indexation.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html).